# Write a program that can that can write a program, in the shortest code possible!

Tags: code-golf

As stated, write a program that is capable to, in an automated manner, write more code and another program and execute that program from itself.

In short, you are asked to write a program that can write another self-standing program itself and enable it to execute in any function.

Do this in the shortest amount of code possible, with the one restriction being that it has to be written in [one of these languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language#languages).

If you need even more specific details, read on:

> You are asked to write a program that will (in an automated manner)
>   write the lines of code needed for another program, and compile that
>   program/execute it from the programmatic structure of the main program
>   itself. The program is not executing the program, but is programmed to
>   write code and then compile/get the OS to execute it while it's still
>   running separately.

Comment: Does the program need to execute the compiled child?

Comment: I've closed this as Too Broad because it's basically saying "write some code that prints any other code." You're going to have to be a little more specific - for example, "write a program that compiles a program that will delete the original code, and then runs it" or something like that (bad example, but you get the idea). Once improvements have been made, I'll be happy to reopen this.

Answer (score 2):

## C: <s>41</s> 38 characters

Pretty much the most trivial solution possible in C.

```c
main(){system("gcc -xc -<<<'main;'");}
```

Comment: Seems like it doesn't matter if the generated program crashes (as long as it compiles), so I guess your inner program can be shortened to `main;` instead of `main(){}`